# PreferredLocalizations available on MonoTouch/iOS

Tags: ios, localization, xamarin.ios, nsbundle

Looking at the Apple Developer Reference, i see that `PreferredLocalizations` are available just as `PreferredLanguages`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

However, it seems that "PreferredLocalizations" is not implemented in `NSBundle`. Am i missing something here? I am `using MonoTouch.Foundation`

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's presently missing from MonoTouch. The best and fastest way to get it is to fill a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and ask for it.

In many cases (like this one) it's easy to give a workaround that will work with existing releases of MonoTouch.

Note that your link is for OSX, not [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and some types, including `NSBundle` have a few differences between the two (but in the case of `preferredLocalizations` it exists in both OS).

**UPDATE**

I added this for the next (it will be 5.3.5) version of MonoTouch. In the meantime here's a workaround:

```
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
...
var bh = NSBundle.MainBundle.Handle;
var sel = Selector.GetHandle ("preferredLocalizations");
var pl = NSArray.StringArrayFromHandle (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (bh, sel));
Console.WriteLine (pl [0]); // en
```